# Update jquery to search for subject from text area

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm currently using a jquery/php tutorial to search for certain hashtags on Twitter however I'm having to hard code the search criteria into the jquery code (see below e.g. London).

I have a text/search area on my site and I'd want to be able to search for any subject/hashtag from that text area with a search button however I can't seem to figure out how to update the function in jquery to select this query. I've looked on the jquery site of how to update this with no luck. Many Thanks

```
//click the go button
$(function(event) {

event.preventDeafult();    

//get the value of the input
var myHashtag = $('#hashtagSearch').val();

//for testing
twitterFeed(myHashtag);
});

function twitterFeed(myHashtag)  {
JQTWEET = {

//assign the value of the input to the search 
search: myHashtag,
user: '', //username
numTweets: 21, //number of tweets
appendTo: '#jstwitter',
useGridalicious: true,
template: '<div class="item">{IMG}<div class="tweet-wrapper"><span class="text">{TEXT}</span>\
<span class="time"><a href="{URL}" target="_blank">{AGO}</a></span>\
by <span class="user">{USER}</span></div></div>',
// core function of jqtweet
// https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search
loadTweets: function() {
var request;
// different JSON request {hash|user}
if (JQTWEET.search) {
request = {
q: JQTWEET.search,
count: JQTWEET.numTweets,
api: 'search_tweets'
}
} else {
request = {
q: JQTWEET.user,
count: JQTWEET.numTweets,
api: 'statuses_userTimeline'
}
}
$.ajax({
url: 'grabtweets.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: request,
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

     if (data.httpstatus == 200) {
         if (JQTWEET.search) data = data.statuses;
var text, name, img;    

try {
// append tweets into page
for (var i = 0; i < JQTWEET.numTweets; i++) {        
img = '';
url = 'http://twitter.com/' + data[i].user.screen_name + '/status/' + data[i].id_str;
try {
if (data[i].entities['media']) {
img = '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + data[i].entities['media'][0].media_url + '" /></a>';
}
} catch (e) {
//no media
}
$(JQTWEET.appendTo).append( JQTWEET.template.replace('{TEXT}', JQTWEET.ify.clean(data[i].text) )
.replace('{USER}', data[i].user.screen_name)
.replace('{IMG}', img)
.replace('{AGO}', JQTWEET.timeAgo(data[i].created_at) )
.replace('{URL}', url )            
);
}
} catch (e) {
//item is less than item count
}
     if (JQTWEET.useGridalicious) {
     //run grid-a-licious
            $(JQTWEET.appendTo).gridalicious({
                gutter: 13,
                width: 200,
                animate: true
            });    
         }
} else alert('no data returned');
}
});
},
/**
* relative time calculator FROM TWITTER
* @param {string} twitter date string returned from Twitter API
* @return {string} relative time like "2 minutes ago"
*/
timeAgo: function(dateString) {
var rightNow = new Date();
var then = new Date(dateString);
if ($.browser.msie) {
// IE can't parse these crazy Ruby dates
then = Date.parse(dateString.replace(/( \+)/, ' UTC$1'));
}
var diff = rightNow - then;
var second = 1000,
minute = second * 60,
hour = minute * 60,
day = hour * 24,
week = day * 7;
if (isNaN(diff) || diff < 0) {
return ""; // return blank string if unknown
}
if (diff < second * 2) {
// within 2 seconds
return "right now";
}
if (diff < minute) {
return Math.floor(diff / second) + " seconds ago";
}
if (diff < minute * 2) {
return "about 1 minute ago";
}
if (diff < hour) {
return Math.floor(diff / minute) + " minutes ago";
}
if (diff < hour * 2) {
return "about 1 hour ago";
}
if (diff < day) {
return Math.floor(diff / hour) + " hours ago";
}
if (diff > day && diff < day * 2) {
return "yesterday";
}
if (diff < day * 365) {
return Math.floor(diff / day) + " days ago";
}
else {
return "over a year ago";
}
}, // timeAgo()
/**
* The Twitalinkahashifyer!
* http://www.dustindiaz.com/basement/ify.html
* Eg:
* ify.clean('your tweet text');
*/
ify: {
link: function(tweet) {
return tweet.replace(/\b(((https*\:\/\/)|www\.)[^\"\']+?)(([!?,.\)]+)?(\s|$))/g, function(link, m1, m2, m3, m4) {
var http = m2.match(/w/) ? 'http://' : '';
return '<a class="twtr-hyperlink" target="_blank" href="' + http + m1 + '">' + ((m1.length > 25) ? m1.substr(0, 24) + '...' : m1) + '</a>' + m4;
});
},
at: function(tweet) {
return tweet.replace(/\B[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/g, function(m, username) {
return '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' + username + '">@' + username + '</a>';
});
},
list: function(tweet) {
return tweet.replace(/\B[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}\/\w+)/g, function(m, userlist) {
return '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/' + userlist + '">@' + userlist + '</a>';
});
},
hash: function(tweet) {
return tweet.replace(/(^|\s+)#(\w+)/gi, function(m, before, hash) {
return before + '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-hashtag" href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23' + hash + '">#' + hash + '</a>';
});
},
clean: function(tweet) {
return this.hash(this.at(this.list(this.link(tweet))));
}
} // ify
}

alert(myHashtag);        
}
```

The HTML and the Script on the page calling the jquery above is as follows:

```
<p>Enter your hashtag</p>
<input id="hashtagSearch" type="text">
<input id="goButton" type="submit" value="go">
<div id="jstwitter"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#goButton').click( function() {
// start jqtweet!
JQTWEET.loadTweets();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/SnhBZ/

HTML

```
<p>Enter your hashtag</p>
<input id="hashtagSearch" type="text">
<input id="goButton" type="submit" value="go">
```

JQUERY

```
//click the go button
$('#goButton').click( function() {

    //get the value of the input
    var myHashtag = $('#hashtagSearch').val();

    //for testing
    alert(myHashtag);

    JQTWEET = {

    //assign the value of the input to the search 
    search: myHashtag 

    //......put the rest of your code in here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the jquery but it doesn't seem to fire when I hit submit? The following script is on the main page-----<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // start jqtweet!
    JQTWEET.loadTweets();
});  
</script>----- Does this need changing to------ '$('#goButton').click( function() {'----- also? I tried it with no success?

Comment: Have you updated the HTML? The ID of your submit button probably isn't the same as the one in my example

Comment: id="goButton"? Yeah I used your HTML & jquery code so they match. strange I'm not sure why it won't fire.

Comment: Is it alerting the hashtag at all?

Can you paste  what your JQuery is like now?

Comment: It doesn't seem to do anything? I've edited the code in the original post above, it looks like it should work but maybe I'm missing something straight forward. I hope that helps.

Comment: Is this the tutorial you've been following? - http://www.queness.com/resources/html/jstwitter/ ?

If so, theirs doesn't even seem to work. It is from 2011 and twitter have just update their API so you might have to start from scratch unfortunately :(

EDIT: yup, they've updated the tutorial using the new API - http://www.queness.com/post/14004/easiest-way-to-retrieve-twitter-timeline-and-hashtags-twitter-oauth-api-11

Comment: Yeah I'm using the 2nd tutorial which has been updated for the 1.1 API. It works fine when used as it is... but I'd like to be able to search for hashtags without hardcoding it into the javascript. I've been reading other onclick posts on here (SO) but I can't figure out how this works on the code above?

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try it when I get in from work tonight.

Comment: no luck unfortunately....should the jquery call the  $('#goButton').click( function() { twice? It's on the actual page where it loads the tweets and on the jquery code that pulls the raw data.

Comment: It shouldn't be in there twice, only once for when the user clicks the goButton

Comment: that's what I thought. As it's already on the script on the main page ---<script type="text/javascript"> $('#goButton').click( function() { // start jqtweet! JQTWEET.loadTweets(); }); </script>----I therefore removed it from the script that it calls. I've edited the code above on the original post and I tried this last night with no success. I wonder if its something to do with 'twitterfeed' part? Should this refer to JQTWEET?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

//get the value of the input
var myHashtag = $('#hashtagSearch').val();

JQTWEET = {

//assign the value of the input to the search 
search: myHashtag 

//......put the rest of your code in here
}
});
```

The above code works but with the following textarea and onClick

```
<textarea id="hashtagSearch" type="text">NFL</textarea>
<button id="goButton" type="submit" onClick="JQTWEET.loadtweets();"></button>
```

The problem is the var term (NFL) has to hard coded in the textarea and won't work when entering new text into the textarea?? Any ideas on how to make this work with a search term entered on the spot?